# Python library to aggregate git user contributions from disparate repos

Tags: python, git, github-api, bitbucket-api

Is there a python library/widget that aggregates one's contributions over heterogeneous version control systems (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket, local git repos, etc.), and creates a calendar heatmap (in the style of the GitHub profile contribution heatmap) of one's total git contributions?

I know there are several front ends available for these heatmaps:

https://github.com/DKirwan/calendar-heatmap

https://github.com/wa0x6e/cal-heatmap

But my intuition tells me there probably already exists a library to aggregate statistics/information about many git repos. And that I just haven't had any luck finding it.

Otherwise I imagine the easiest way to do this would be by querying the vcs hosting websites' apis for user contributions, and registering local repos to gather the relevant data, and piping that to the heatmap.